# Как без ID вывести дочерний элемент отдельно от родительского из кастомной таксономии?

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот у меня есть кастомная таксономия "vehicles" и в ней у элементов 3 уровня иерархии.
То есть:
Родитель > ребёнок > правнук
И этих 3х уровневых иерархий у меня очень много, а элементов у меня вообще 377. Не уверен что объясняю правильно и понятно поэтому вот скриншот для наглядности

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня стоит задача вывести на странице товара каждый уровень иерархии отдельно.
То есть на сайте это должно выглядеть так. 
 
Year(Родитель) - список со всеми годами - отдельно 
Make(Ребёнок) - список со всеми производителями - отдельно 
Model(Правнук) - Список со всеми моделями - отдельно

Как мне это сделать? Вручную вбивать ID не очень бы хотелось, напомню что элементов 377. Что посоветуете? 
Да я могу использовать

```
$args = array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'taxonomy' => 'vehicles',
    'depth' => 1
);

wp_list_categories($args);
```

что бы вывести отдельно "родителя", а как быть с "ребёнком" и "правнуком"? Буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Year(Родитель) - список со всеми годами - отдельно
- Make(Ребёнок) - список со всеми производителями - отдельно
- Model(Правнук) - Список со всеми моделями - отдельно

Вы сами написали, что иерархия у вас совсем не правильная. Делаете 3 таксономии отдельно и все.

Comment: Нет, вы видимо не правильно меня поняли. Я же написал выше что проблем с выводом "родителя" у меня нет.

Comment: А почему у вас нет нужного id родителя?

Comment: Вы смотрели скриншот?

Comment: Используйте child_of => родителя, чтобы получить правнука

Comment: Я могу получить ID родителя, но их сотни. Вот в чём проблема.

Comment: Судя по скриншоту видно, что вы срезаете углы и лепите 3 таксономии в 1

Comment: Да опишите вы задачу нормально.....

Comment: Но в целом я понял что вам надо, но ответ вам не понравится

Comment: Извините, не совсем понял что значит - "срезаю углы"? А как правильно было сделать? Посоветуйте пожалуйста.

Comment: Я же написал, элементов 377. Это получается что мне нужно сотни раз писать ID в child_of =>
Правильно?

Comment: 3 таксономии? То есть вместо одной таксономии vehicles делать:
Таксономию - Year;
Таксономию - Make;
Таксономию - Model.
Так?

Comment: Именно. И связи делаешь через нужный пост. В дальнейшем вам это съекономит кучу времени

Comment: Спасибо большое! А что значит - "И связи делаешь через нужный пост"?

Comment: Для чего вы сделали таксономии? Чтобы разделять какой-то нужный вам тип постов на группы

Comment: Но в моём случае это не посты. Это будет три селекта на странице товара. Выбирая поэтапно Year > Make > Model человек проверяет подходит ли ему запчасть или нет. В моём случае точно стоит разделять на разные таксономии?